# C++ Finding local maxima in 2d array

Tags: c++, arrays

I am trying to write a program that finds and prints all the local maxima in this 2D array, looking at the 2nd column only.  Think I am on the right track but don't know how to proceed and it doesn't give the correct output. Thanks.

```
int main()
{
float array[7][2] = { { 1, 22 }, { 2, 15 }, { 3, 16 }, { 4, 14 }, { 5, 13 }, {6,19}, {7,12} };
int i;
float before = 0, after = 0, localmax = 0;
int Index = 0;

for (i = 0; i<7; i++)
{
    if ((array[i][1] >= before) && (array[i][1] >= after))
    {
        before = array[i-1][1];
        after = array[i + 1][1];
        localmax = array[i][1];
        Index = i;
    }
}

cout << "The local maxima in the array are " << localmax << endl;
cout << "The corresponding values in the array are " << array[Index][0] << endl;
_getch();
return 0;
```

}

Comment: What output does it give, and what is the output you expect?

Comment: The local max as 15, but obviously want 22, 16 & 19 instead

Comment: "all the local maxima", yet your output is a single 'localmax' ... so which is it?

Comment: Yes I admit I have made an error as I am after all the maxima

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are overwriting your (single) float localmax.

There are two solutions to your problem:

Nr. 1: You could print localmax everytime you find one (put the cout in the for loop)

```
int main()
{
float array[7][2] = { { 1, 22 }, { 2, 15 }, { 3, 16 }, { 4, 14 }, { 5, 13 }, {6,19}, {7,12} };
int i;
float before = 0, after = 0, localmax = 0;
int Index = 0;

for (i = 0; i<7; i++)
{
    if ((array[i][1] >= before) && (array[i][1] >= after))
    {
        before = array[i-1][1];
        after = array[i + 1][1];
        localmax = array[i][1];
        cout << "A local maxima is: " << localmax << endl;
        Index = i;
    }
}

_getch();
return 0;
}
```

Nr. 2: You create a localmax vector and use push_back to save any local maxima you find.

```
    int main()
{
float array[7][2] = { { 1, 22 }, { 2, 15 }, { 3, 16 }, { 4, 14 }, { 5, 13 }, {6,19}, {7,12} };
int i;
float before = 0, after = 0, localmax = 0;
int Index = 0;
std::vector<float> localMaxVector;

for (i = 0; i<7; i++)
{
    if ((array[i][1] >= before) && (array[i][1] >= after))
    {
        before = array[i-1][1];
        after = array[i + 1][1];
        localMaxVector.push_back(array[i][1]);
        Index = i;
    }
}

cout << "The local maxima in the array are " << endl;
for( std::vector<float>::const_iterator i = localMaxVector.begin(); i != localMaxVector.end(); ++i)
std::cout << *i << ' ';
 _getch();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note that this is just to give you the gist of what you should do. I just copied your code and modified the relevant parts. I'm pretty sure your program should crash before doing anything, since it seems like you are trying to access array[-1] in your first iteration.

Answer (score 0):

You don't verify the array index before setting "before" and "after", I'm surprised your code didn't crash (i-1 and i+1).

I don't have much time so I haven't tried it, but it should work.

```
int main()
{
    float array[7][2] = { { 1, 22 }, { 2, 15 }, { 3, 16 }, { 4, 14 }, { 5, 13 }, { 6, 19 }, { 7, 12 } };
    int i;
    float before = 0, after = 0;
    int Index = 0;

    for (i = 0; i<7; i++)
    {
        if (i > 0)
        {
            before = array[i-1][1];
        }
        if (i < 6)
        {
            after = array[i+1][1];
        }
        if ((i == 0 || array[i][1] >= before) && (i == 6 or array[i][1] >= after))
        {
            //when you're at the very first point, you don't have to verify the 'before' variable, and for the very last point, you don't have to verify 'after'
            cout << array[i][1] << " at position " << i << " is a maxima" << endl;
        }
    }

    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

If you want to keep the results, you can use the std::vector like Thomas.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your loop is correct.  If you inserted an element {0, 20} at the start of your array, your code would return 19 and 22 (assuming 'before' remains at 0 when i == 0).  I expect you want 22, 16, 19.  If so, your loop should look like this:

```
for (i = 0; i<7; i++)
{
    if ((i == 0 || array[i][1] > array[i - 1][1]) && (i == 6 || array[i][1] >= array[i + 1][1]))
    {
        localmax = array[i][1];
        Index = i;
    }
}
```